# Queryset from queryset in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model, Project, that contains a list of Users, with the many to many field employees. This M2M field goes through another model, ProjectEmployee and I was wondering how I can get a lit of all Projects given user belongs to?

I can get a queryset of all the ProjectEmployee models that a user belongs to, but how do I get a queryset of the Projects from this?

ProjectEmployee.objects.filter(user=user)

Comment: Can you please share the relevant models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just filter with:

```
Project.objects.filter(employees=user)
```

Django will automatically make a join with the table of the `ProjectEmployee` model, and filter on the foreign key.